# .htaccess RewriteBase for development env not working

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, base-url, html5mode

This is my .htaccess file

```html
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /myapp_dev/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^(signup|signin)/?$ $1.html [L,NC]

  RewriteRule ^home/?$ signup.html [L,NC]

  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

And in my html pages, I have this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  
  <!-- Something here -->
  
  
  <script src="public/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="public/libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting the server to request for `http://localhost/myapp_dev/public/libs/angular/angular.js`

But it is requesting for this url which anyways doesn't exist.

```
http://localhost/public/libs/angular/angular.js
```

Any issues in .htaccess code?

Comment: Just add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/myapp_dev/" />`

Comment: But I found thats not a best practice as we need to change it again in testing, production servers.

Comment: Then keep exact same directory structure across the dev, testing, prod. Rewrite rules or .htaccess are not causing this, it is use of relative paths in `src="..."` that is causing it.

Comment: Yes I agree but the issue is, in production servers we will access like http://example.com/signin and in dev it will be something like http://localhost/myapp_dev/signin. In live/testing environments I require base url to be /

Comment: That’s not what RewriteBase does. // The client creates the absolute URL from the relative one, and since you are using `<base href="/">` it has no other choice than to request http://localhost/public/libs/angular/angular.js. I’d recommend that you change your test setup instead. Instead of reaching your app via `localhost/myapp_dev/`, create a local domain `myapp.local` or something like that, and set up a VHost that points to the correct folder - then you don’t have to worry about making paths “fit” the current environment any more.

Answer (score 0):

On development host **create a new .htaccess in your site root** and have an additional rule to handle these static paths:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^public/libs/.+$ /myapp_dev/$0 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```